# how to correctly in order get the country, town, street ..in Google Place Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-api

I´m creating a service where user can go to an address anywhere in the world. First I thought Google Places API would be grate for this but looking at this picture(below) the question is how to filter out, in correct order the country, town, street address. First I think splitting the result by the "," but seeing in the picture that **Arab Emirates** is using "-" instead of "," makes thing harder right. 
The Place Autocomplete result always have the country name at the end, then comes(usually) the town in this country, looking at the picture the first result is Bangladesh embassy in United States, it ends with the country name right but after that comes "DC" and after that comes "Washington".

How is anyone suppose to use this data when there is no clear logic in what is what!?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Since my users can ask for any address anywhere I set the `LatLngBounds=null` and `AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_NONE`.

I tried also the  `AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS` but the result is slightly the same.

I get the feeling I must use [[International-address-format]](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html) to detect what country the user is asking for and pic the correct **address-format** and then correctly split the Place Autocomplete result.

Comment: I found a solution using [android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView](https://github.com/seatgeek/android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView).
They created the view because they where having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use an AutocompleteFilter containing a set of place types, which you can use to restrict the results to one or more types of place.
Here is the link for more : 
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Google places api gives better results for places auto complete , looks like you have not used the filter ,use Autocomplete filter to filter the place types.

if you are using google places api for android , please use the below link.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment

if you using java script api use below.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete#try-it-yourself